SageMATH failed to solve ODE with Symbolic Integration
I'm trying to solve an exact integration of a nonlinear ODE using SageMath.
I'm trying to find time function $x = x(t)$ integrating ODE $\dot{x} = b(2+\sqrt(1-x^2))(1-x^2)$ with SAGEMATH code below:
t = var('t')
x=function('x')(t)
var('b', domain='positive')
ode = diff(x,t)==b*(2+sqrt(1-x^2))*(1-x^2)
sol = desolve(ode, x,ivar=t); sol

b is a constant at equation.
But SAGEMATH returns notifications like "RuntimeError: ECL says: Error executing code in Maxima: changevar: fourth argument must be an atom; found: 'x(_SAGE_VAR_t)" and "ECL says: Error executing code in Maxima: changevar: fourth argument must be an atom; found: 'x(_SAGE_VAR_t)".
Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this?
Thanks.

It would be worth trying to solve it directly in Maxima the original error message there may be clearer.

Obviously some kind of substitution is required, like 1=x*x+u*u or x=sin(u). This substitution of x fails for some reason. You probably should submit this as issue in a bug tracker for sagemath.

Lutz Lehmann, I tried that substitution. Doing calculations by my hand, I solved the integral. But the relation of x with t is a TRANSCEDENTAL EQUATION in which it is not possible to isolate x as function of t. I have t as function of x. Is SageMath capable of solving transcendental equations exactly?
